# JetBrains Toolbox crashes on startup with GLX error

Tags: 16.04, java, crash

I got the latest Jetbrains toolbox and untarred it. When I run it this happens:

```
/h/e/j/jetbrains-toolbox-1.3.2421 $ ./jetbrains-toolbox
Could not initialize GLX
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried with --disable-gpu but it dosen't have any effect

Comment: I'll go out on a limb here, and indicate that since this is a paid-for program, perhaps you could tap into their support?

Comment: There's already a ticket about it, but it's with no updates from months now. Perhaps I could find some sort of workaround here

Comment: The build you are mentioning seems to be from May 17. I think they are updating this thing pretty regularly. So... fingers crossed! :) I don't have the same exact problem you have, but it crashes on startup as well. :(